# Is it possible to use Python 3.10 in Google Colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I would like to use the Structural Pattern Matching feature from Python 3.10 in Google Colab so using the commands

```
!sudo apt-get install python3.10
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 1
!sudo update-alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.10
```

I was able to make `!python --version` output 3.10.0, but the `print(sys.version)` still outputs 3.7.12 in code cells and so the match cases statement raises **SyntaxError**

```
number = 1

match number:
    case 0:
        print("Error")
    case _:
        print(number)
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Just because there is a Python 3.10 on the system does not mean the notebook is using it. Did you tell the notebook to use the newer Python?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't think I did, but I don't know how to, all the commands I used are described in the question, what else should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12Uy1fTJy4XQDMdXVM_5XJ0iGEdCDOgYf).

- make a copy of it
- run the first cell
- reload (Ctrl + R, or Cmd + R)
- run the second cell

See this [video demo](https://youtu.be/t1yCmSyFEQY) by 1littlecoder.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at your github repo and it seems you have been putting a lot of work on making everyone's life in Colab easier with this lib

Comment: @korakot do you know how to turn on syntax highlighting?

Comment: @vak I just notice that the syntax highlight is gone. I don't know how to turn it back on. Maybe it need to detect the kernel is python3. So, py310 kernel will disable the highlight.

Comment: @korakot, I guess there is some extension or plugin responsible for syntax highlighting and it is just missed during installation of py310 and py311 kernels. If we'd knew which plugin it is and how to install it...